# re-open vscode without last workspace or last files

Tags: visual-studio-code

I wish set `VSCode` to be launched clean, no last workspace or last files opened..
is this possible?

I use it as unity3d debugger and annoying me all the times that opens a previous workspace (no workspaces saved)

thanks in advance

Comment: "window.restoreWindows": "none", in your settings will always open with an empty workspace.

Comment: thanks @Mark!  I tried but doesn't affect, I launch vscode and I got the last workspace/opened files

Comment: I had to restart vscode a few times for it to take effect for some reason - I think people have had some issues with it - but now it works every time for me.  [I actually deleted and typed the "none" myself the last time it seemed to work and closed the settings file before closing vscode]..  So it seems wonky but is now working well for me.  Just try a few restarts.

Answer (score 15):

Besides my comment above, also see [open a new window](http://window.openWithoutArgumentsInNewWindow), v1.22 released **today** if you prefer to open via a command line.

> Controls if a new empty window should open when starting a second
>   instance without arguments or if the last running instance should get
>   focus.   // - on: open a new empty window   // - off: the last active
>   running instance will get focus   // Note that there can still be
>   cases where this setting is ignored (e.g. when using the -new-window
>   or -reuse-window command line option).

```
  "window.openWithoutArgumentsInNewWindow": "on"
```

But the setting

```
"window.restoreWindows": "none"
```

should also work for opening in other ways (but seems to require a few restarts - perhaps it has been fixed as of 1.22?).

Comment: exactly @Mark, happens this, with 2 windows opened, one with the latest workspace and one with the new

Comment: @ghiboz did it help you?

Comment: Adding both of these settings worked for me!

Answer (score 9):

According to the [VSCode command line documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/command-line), you can use `-n` or `--new-window` flag to open new session without any old files.

I just checked and it works.

The full command to run VSCode is (on my PC):

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe" -n
```

or just

```
code -n
```

**Tip:** You can change the shortcut for VSCode to include the `-n` flag so it opens new session always.

Comment: thanks, and is not a config to set internally this feature?

Comment: No, however, this can help you: workspace specific files are in a .vscode folder at the root. For example, tasks.json for the Task Runner and launch.json for the debugger. Maybe you can delete them before starting debugging.

Answer (score 2):

None of the other solutions were working for me.

Recently hit this issue where I tried to do a find and replace with 15000 files and vscode crashed while trying to save all those files. I closed the window and re-opened but it kept trying to re-open those 15000 files and would crash again.

I was able to fix this by deleting the corresponding workspace folder (search by folder name) in

`/Users/{username}/Library/Application Support/Code/User/workspaceStorage`

Then when you reopen that folder nothing is saved or open.

Comment: I had similar issue, but simply removing workspace folder did not help. There is folder "/Code/Backup" in VSCode AppData folder that kept backup of bugged out workspace and copies of 34004(!) files that were opened in that workspace. Deleting the folder of backup for that workspace and removing that workspace from json file "workspaces.json" in backups is what solved it for me. It was under "emptyWorkspaceInfos" section of the backup file.